# How to update the database, if the user rate a product in ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to update the database columns "rate_score" and "rate_number" if the user rate it. "rate_score" shows the whole number of rates that all users are rated. "rate_number" shows the whole number of users who rate it. If the user does not rate the product, he can see the average rating value. But my code is not working.

Here is my PHP code.

```
$jsqla = mysql_query("select id,name,rate_score,rate_number,video_image from products where genre='$genre' limit 0,5");

if($jrowa['rate_number'] > 0){ 
  $ratea = $jrowa['rate_score'] / $jrowa['rate_number']; 
}else{ 
  $ratea = 0; 
}
```

Here is my HTML code.

```
<input class="rating form-control input-star-rate" name="rating" value="<?php echo $ratea; ?>" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="0.3" data-size="xs" style="display: none; text-align: center;"/>
```

Here is my jQuery code.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var $stars = $('.input-star-rate');

        $stars.bind('change', function() {
          var $this = $(this); 
          var ratingValue = $this.val();
          var id = $this.attr("id");
          var num = parseInt("$this.attr("rate_number")")+1;

          $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "update_star_rate.php", 
            data : {product_id: id, rate_score: ratingValue, rate_number: num},
            success : function() {
                alert(ratingValue);
            }
          });
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the content of "update_star_rate.php"

```
<?php
    require_once("scripts/dcon.php");

    $rate_score=$_POST['rate_score'];
    $product_id=$_POST['id'];
    $rate_number=$_POST['rate_number'];

    $rate = "UPDATE products SET rate_score=$rate_score, rate_number=$rate_number WHERE id=$product_id" ;

    $result = mysql_query($rate) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: what value are you expecting in `alert(ratingValue)`? You are not echoing any value back from `update_star_rate.php`...

Comment: And stop using `mysql_query`. This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
data : 'product_id='+id+'&rate_score='+ratingValue+'&rate_number='+num,
```

Instead of

```
data : {product_id: id, rate_score: ratingValue, rate_number: num},
```

before inserting, check all variable are working. (use alert).

Answer (score 2):

```
require_once("scripts/dcon.php");
if (isset($_POST['rate_score']) && !empty($_POST['rate_score'])){
    $rate_score=$_POST['rate_score'];
} //this will set only when data comes 
if (isset($_POST['rate_id']) && !empty($_POST['rate_id'])){
    $product_id=$_POST['id'];
} //this will set only when data comes 
if (isset($_POST['rate_number']) && !empty($_POST['rate_number'])){
   $rate_number=$_POST['rate_number'];
} //this will set only when data comes 

$rate = "UPDATE products SET rate_score=$rate_score, rate_number=$rate_number WHERE id=$product_id" ;

$result = mysql_query($rate) or die(mysql_error());
```

if your ajax data come correctly then you will update data